# Stacked columns in bar chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is it possible to make stacked columns in a bar chart like follows?

- Black column (3rd from right) consists from the data in `H2+I2 (=G2)`
- Red column (2nd from right) consists from the data in `H3+I3 (=G3)`
- Grey column (1st from right) consists from the data in `H4+I4 (=G4)`

I have covered these columns with the rectangular forms, how they should look like. I know, it looks weird :-)
[image: My chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but need to reshape your data and possibly sacrifice the data below the chart. I recreated the chart using stacked bar chart. Every fill had be manually customized. If you play around with this sort of idea, you may find a way to better automate. Perhaps create a manual legend rather than repeat A/B/C over and over.

First select D1 through E25 and create your stacked bar chart. Then click on the chart, "select data", and edit your horizontal labels by selecting B2 through C25. Make manual adjustments until it looks good.

[image]